# Using $V{PAGE_NUMBER} evaluated Now and Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I use *iReport 5.0.0* and I have some problem about using variable $V{Page_number}.

I wish to use the variable $V{PAGE_NUMBER} evaluated "Now" and evaluated "Report" in the same expression of a text field. I need to compare the current page with the total number of page in a conditional expression.

Example in page 1: I want to print "to be con't page 2", and so on. And in the last page I want to print "the Grand Total is : ".

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can't have a text field with both evaluation times.
Your Problem can be solved on two ways:

1. Use the band Summary:
   The Summary band is only shown on the last Page here you can enter "the Grand Total is : "
   Don't forget to mark the Page Footer Band as not pintet on last page (by Print When Expression)
2. You can make 2 Textfields and lay them over each other. Then you have to fill the Print When Expression so that text 1 is printed on every page and the Summary is only printed on the last page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I can't do. Because the text field that I want to fill the expression it's in the table, and my table is in Summary section. Please help me to solve this problem again.